# json and php news system

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have access to the api which generates news in json.
for example for news id #9 I can get date from:

```
someserver.com/core/news/9
```

this page generates json data for the news.

How I can parse this date using jquery and make news system that will include all newses?

Comment: So where exactly are you calling this URL from? Client side (JavaScript) or server side (PHP)?

Comment: It will be better to use javascript instead of php if it's not too slow to parse date in javascript

Answer (score 1):

Using `jQuery.GetJSON()`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

However the API provider must support [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) otherwise you will run into browser restrictions. ([Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy))

Comment: Yeah I am using jquery getJSON function in another part of the website but I need it in this current situation.

Answer (score 0):

Incase you change your mind, you can also do this with php (without browser restrictions, though the server would php).

```
$newsID = 9;
$json = file_get_contents("someserver.com/core/news/".$newsID);
$news = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($news);
```

Comment: thanks **mazzzzz** but if u know javascript way to do this but not for only news #9 :) for a lot of newses

Comment: That's why I made the 9 a variable, and if I remember correctly, you can't pull json data from another server with javascript/jquery (security feature)